# box.com authentication with lighttpd and openssl

Tags: openssl, lighttpd, box-api

I am trying to authenticate on box.com via their api and php.

I've managed to load up the box.com login and then grant the access, but the next point, when box.com forwards me to my callback I get this error:

Error: it was not possible to open the OAuth access token URL: establishing SSL connections requires the OpenSSL extension enabled

The server is a basic openwrt router, with lighttpd and openssl. I can access my files via https:// but box.com does not work.

Any hints?

Comment: Can your router connect to any other site via HTTPS? (e.g. [https://google.com](https://google.com))

Comment: Is your app written in PHP? I think this error is coming from your app - it is trying to connect to the Box API via HTTPS to swap the code for the access token, but your PHP doesn't have OpenSSL compiled in - http://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php

Comment: How can I check that OpenSSL has been compiled in my PHP. I installed php from the repo, not manually...

Comment: I checked, no openssl was configured in php, I managed to do it, not it works! Thanks a million!